# How do I update persistent data after publishing the app?

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

As of now, my app contains an array and the user can manipulate the order of items in it by dispatching actions. I'm using redux persist and even if I directly change the array elements by editing the source file, the array does not update unless I clear the app cache.
What are my options to update this kind of persistent data after I publish it to the store without forcing users to clear the cache?

Comment: If i understand correctly, you wanna reset redux without the user's pressing a button? am I right?

Comment: Not reset, but update. For example:
['apple', 'banana', 'orange'].  It is saved in the user's local storage. Now How can I change banana to peach without forcing the user to clear their cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you looking for is **migrations**.
How it works:

1. Load user's previous state from local storage on app start
2. Update fields you need

Here is a setup [example](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/docs/migrations.md)